# https://schema.org/ - is @id kept on all the pages of the site

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I am thinking about how to organize the microdata for my site.
On my home page I declare my organization:

```
"@id" : "https://www.my.site/#org"
```

I am thinking to keep this only on my homepage. Can I reference this id on other pages?

```
"author"            : {"@id": "https://www.my.site/#org"}
```

Is the id saved like a global variable?

Thanks

Comment: yes, you can - and should - use it wherever relevant. if the site is about `@Person` (you) then you may `author` other content on other pages. `@id` serves to link all pages to "you"

Comment: I find testing tools like the ones from Google complain if it's just the id used, so I also include and repeat the basic information they require on each page.